# HTML not rendering properly in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working with the angularJS tutorial on code school, my code keeps rendering wrongly on my webpage. Would appreciate any help please. Here's my index.html and app.js codes below:

for the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>
    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
    <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the app.js:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);
  app.controller('StoreController', function(this){
  this.products = gems;
});
var gems = [
  { name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    images: [
    {
      full: 'dodecahedron-01-full.jpg', 
      thumb: 'dodecahedron-01-thumb.jpg'
    }]
    canPurchase: false
    soldOut: false
  }, 
  {
    name: "Pentagonal Gem",
    price: 5.95,
    description: "..."
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false
  }
  ];

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

1) You don't need to put "this" as a parameter to the function in the controller creation:

```
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
          this.products = gems;
});
```

2) multiple typos (missing commas) in your data which is causing the Javascript not to parse.

```
var gems = [
  { name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    images: [
    {
      full: 'dodecahedron-01-full.jpg', 
      thumb: 'dodecahedron-01-thumb.jpg'
    }],
    canPurchase: false,
    soldOut: false
  }, 
  {
    name: "Pentagonal Gem",
    price: 5.95,
    description: "...",
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false
  }
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff :).much appreciated but you didn't point out where I had the typos :)

Comment: You can simply copy over with what I wrote, but specifically  inside your objects you are missing necessary commas. In the first one, after the ] in the images array, "canPurchase: false". In the second one, after description: "..."